# Create an incremental method for users ID in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I was trying to create a database structure where every user that register in the app, gets an incremental ID stored in firebase, but I am not very clear how to do it.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6GvW.png)

Comment: Why does it needs to be a number? Firebase can generate ids for your, but they are not numbers.

Comment: Why not use the uid that is coming from the auth process?

Comment: @AlexMamo I know its a better idea, but Im asked to do it in this way.

Comment: @peakystewie What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried creating a counter variable and incrementing it everytime a user is registered but the problem is when the app is restarted the counter starts from 0 again. I think the logic is that I should create a variable of the latest child added in firebase and increment it, but I am not finding a way how to refer to the latest child added.

Comment: "how to refer to the latest child added"? Get it right from the database, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, thats the idea.

Comment: So why not to do it?

Comment: @AlexMamo I dont know exactly any method to retrieve that latest child added, store it in a variable (like counter) and increment it when a user registers.

Comment: There is no predifined method to do that, you should create yourself or you can use Cloud Functions.

Comment: @AlexMamo any hint or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Is it important to you that the ID is incremental? In distributed systems, there is always a risk of ID collisions.

It is good practice to use a globally unique ID (UUID) to identify users. These IDs do never collide.

Dart implementation: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uuid

Usage:

```
String uuid = Uuid().v4();
```

Comment: If it's about guid, firebase generate these for you. You shouldn't do it yourself

Comment: Im asked to do it incrementally, I know its not a good idea. But the fact that is incremental it means that cannot have collisions, since for every user added, the ID goes +1.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do something like this(pseudo code)?

```
var allUsers = await Firebase.instance.collection('users').getDocuments();
var newID = allUsers.documents.length + 1;
// then use the generated ID to save for a new user
```

Comment: This is for Firestore I think, not Real Time Database.

Comment: @peakystewie doesn’t matter, the same logic applies.